# Nested model data not poplating after validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form - person/user, 1:1 - with the user form being the outer form.

Each time a validation error arises and the user is redirected back to the page the nested person attributes are not loaded.

Everything saves down correctly if no validation errors arise.

At this point I'm drawing blanks in my searches and my attempts to fix this.

I've tried putting the "has_one/belongs_to" relationship both ways and neither seems to make a difference. In the controller I've tried as many variations of setting the data as I can think of - some result in no saving but none have allowed me to return a populated person object on error.

Any help is appreciated.

Rails version: 3.1.3

Main form:

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => { :action => :create } do |f| -%>
    …    
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :login %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :login %></td>
    </tr>    
    ...
    <%= render :partial => '/users/form', :locals => { :f => f } %>
    ...        
    <%= submit_tag 'Register' %>    
<% end %>
```

Nested form, plus more main form:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:person) do |person_form| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= person_form.label :first %></td>
        <td><%= person_form.text_field :first %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= person_form.label :last %></td>
        <td><%= person_form.text_field :last %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= person_form.label :email %></td>
        <td><%= person_form.text_field :email %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= person_form.label :phone %></td>
        <td><%= person_form.text_field :phone %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

<tr>
    <td><%= f.label :challenge_question %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :challenge_question %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><%= f.label :challenge_answer %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :challenge_answer %></td>
</tr>
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :person

    devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable

    attr_accessible :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :challenge_question, :challenge_answer, :person_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :person

    validates_presence_of :login
    validates_length_of :challenge_question, :maximum => 400
    validates_length_of :challenge_answer, :maximum => 400

    ...
end
```

Person:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    validates_presence_of :email, :first, :last
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates_length_of :email, :within => 3..200
    validates_length_of :first, :maximum => 200
    validates_length_of :last, :maximum => 200
    validates_length_of :phone, :maximum => 20, :allow_nil => true
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "is not a valid email address."

    # prevents a user from submitting a crafted form that bypasses activation
    # anything else you want your user to change should be added here.
    attr_accessible :email, :first, :last, :phone, :token, :cc_token
end
```

When the page renders I've done an inspect on @user as well as @user.person and get the following:

@user:

```
{"challenge_question"=>"", "encrypted_password"=>"", "created_at"=>nil, "failed_attempts"=>0, "updated_at"=>nil, "confirmation_sent_at"=>nil, "last_sign_in_ip"=>nil, "role"=>1, "last_sign_in_at"=>nil, "sign_in_count"=>0, "id"=>nil, "current_sign_in_ip"=>nil, "reset_password_token"=>nil, "person_id"=>nil, "challenge_answer"=>"", "disabled"=>false, "locked_at"=>nil, "confirmation_token"=>nil, "current_sign_in_at"=>nil, "remember_created_at"=>nil, "reset_password_sent_at"=>nil, "login"=>"asdf", "unlock_token"=>nil, "confirmed_at"=>nil, "email"=>""}
```

@user.person:

```
{"cc_city"=>nil, "token"=>nil, "last"=>"", "id"=>nil, "cc_token"=>nil, "address_id"=>nil, "phone"=>"", "first"=>"asdf", "email"=>""}
```

Comment: Updated issue description to include screen output showing variable population.

Comment: I am also seeing this in the logs, despite having attr_accessor :person_attributes set: "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: person"

Comment: Another update... I found a place in my controller that was explicitly setting the person. Commenting it out results in the user saving but not the person. Obviously there is a problem with my relationship. Just haven't  pinned it down yet...

Comment: I have a fix for this but SO won't let me post it for 4 more hours as my reputation is under 100... Will post back then...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this worked, but this seems to have fixed it:

From:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:person) do |person_form| %>
```

To:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:person, @user.person) do |person_form| %>
```

The documentation seems to indicate that the former should have worked. I haven't dug into the underlying code yet to see why this didn't work though.